# TypeError: 'writeHead' of undefined node js

Tags: node.js

Im new in `node.js. WriteHead()` function is continuously giving me typeError. Though I have used as `response.wrtieHead(200,{'Context-Type':'text/plain'})` and giving the same error.Please help.
Here is my code.

```
    var http = require('http');
    var fs = require('fs');
    function send404Response(response){
    response.writeHead(200,{"content-Type":"text/plain"});
    response.write("404 paage");
    response.end();

    }

    function onRequest(request,response){

    if(response.method== 'GET' && response.url('/') ){

      response.writeHead(200, {"content-Type":"text/html"});
      fs.createReadStream("./index.html").pipe(response);
    }
    else{
      send404Response();
    }

  }
  http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
  console.log("server is running");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just forgotten to send response in your send404Response function :

```
    var http = require('http');
    var fs = require('fs');

    function send404Response(response){
        response.writeHead(200,{"content-Type":"text/plain"});
        response.write("404 paage");
        response.end();
    }

    function onRequest(request,response){

        if (request.method== 'GET' && request.path == '/') {
            response.writeHead(200, {"content-Type":"text/html"});
            fs.createReadStream("./index.html").pipe(response);
        }
        else{
            send404Response(response);
        }

    }
    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
    console.log("server is running");
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks. Its now running but throw me 404 but it should go to index.html file, right?@Sparw

Comment: Can you display request.path just before the "if" condition ?

Comment: Its now working fine and thanks for your cooperations.